# ASP.NET Core Blazor Hybrid as single-file application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, maui

Some time ago, I build a Blazor Server application and encapsulated it into an [Electron.NET](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET) app so that I can ship it as a single-file executable.

On [Build 2022](https://mybuild.microsoft.com/), Microsoft announced [ASP.NET Core Blazor Hybrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid) with .NET MAUI.

Does anyone know whether a Blazor Hybrid app with .NET MAUI can also be shipped as a single-file executable? Or is it the pseudo-single-file like we have today for ASP.NET Core projects (with `exe` file and `wwwroot` folder)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a bit of confusion. You *want* static files to be stored on disk, because reading files from an actual file is a lot cheaper to handle and cache, using the OS's and SSD disk's cache. That said, you *can* load static files from executable resources. It's the same for settings - you *can* bundle `appsettings.json` into the package but don't you want to *change* settings, to connect to different databases or specify different storage folders? At the very least you'd want `appsettings.production.json` outside the bundle

Comment: I removed `appsettings.json` from the question as it seems to confuse. Let's keep performance out of the picture - I'm interested whether I can build a _real_ single-file EXE with Blazor Hybrid for .NET MAUI without further magic as I can do with Electron

Comment: You can already do that with ASP.NET Core. Static files aren't even included unless you add the necessary middleware. Do you mean *real desktop application* instead of *real single-file exe* perhaps? Because Electron.NET does *not* create a single-file web app

Comment: If you want to phrase it like this, then yes, a _real desktop application_ - what Blazor Hybrid always is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, .Net Maui targets WinUI 3, and is a “single project MSIX” package.

See [Publish a .Net Maui App for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/overview).

That **is** a single file, BUT running it starts an install. So the answer is “yes” if goal is a single file that can
be launched,

but “no” if goal is a self-contained executable that runs immediately, without starting an install. If that is goal, open an issue at maui github.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer 